# Can someone explain stacking contexts?

Tags: css, z-index

I recently had a bug where a video player wasn't clickable inside a jquery ui dialog. 
I ended up fixing the problem by overriding the position:relative; with a position:inherit;

Other solutions to the problem included removing the position:relative; entirely or by making the z-index of the player class be something other than 1.

[As I've read](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), these are both indicative of changing the stacking context in this situation which solved my problem. However, I still don't really understand what was going on in my situation or stacking contexts in general. Does anyone else have any good examples/suggesstions as to what may have been going on?

```
<div class="player"> 
    <div id="videoPlayer_wrapper" style=" position: relative; width:580px; height: 192px;">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/flash/player.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="videoPlayer" name="videoPlayer" tabindex="0">
        </object>
    </div> 
</div>
```

where the CSS for player is

```
.player {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: here they have explained it very well..http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: Great article Kingk. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the article you linked by Phillip Walton to be most helpful to me  understanding stacking contexts...  I went on this study safari in the course of debugging an issue of my own.

Note that the pink square with `z-index: 100;` appears below the light blue square with `z-index: 1;` because it's constrained by a stacking context created on `.A` by the `transform`.

[image: output of the jsbin code snippet]

This jsbin is a bit easier to experiment with than the SO inline code: https://jsbin.com/lataga/2/edit?css,output

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.A {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;

  /*
    Adding a transform here creates a
    new stacking context for the children of .A
    */
  transform: translateX(0);

  /*
    several other properties can trigger creation of stacking context,
    including opacity < 1
    */
  /*    opacity: 0.99; */

  /*
    If we raise .A above .B, the children will rise up with it;
    uncomment the following to see:
    */
  /*    z-index: 3; */
}

.a {
  position: relative;

  /*
    even a much higher z-index can't lift .a above .b when
    it is constrained to a lower stacking context
    */
  z-index: 100;

  margin-left: 125px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.B {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 75px;
  /*    z-index: 2; */
  background-color: blue;
}

.b {
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;

  /*
    The following is not necessary: if a z-index is not specified,
    then it is calculated according to the rules of 
    natural stacking order...
    I'm just specifying it explicitly for editorial effect.
    */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  A: 1
  <div class="a">a: 1.100</div>
</div>
<div class="B">
  B: 2
  <div class="b">b: 2.1</div>
</div>
```

---

### Stacking Context

> - Positioning and assigning a z-index value to an HTML element creates a stacking context, (as does assigning non-full opacity).
> - Stacking contexts can be contained in other stacking contexts, and together create a hierarchy of stacking contexts.
> - Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.
> - Each stacking context is self-contained: after the element's contents are stacked, the whole element is considered in the stacking order of the parent stacking context.
>
> Note: The hierarchy of stacking contexts is a subset of the hierarchy of HTML elements, because only certain elements create stacking contexts. We can say that elements that do not create their own stacking contexts are assimilated by the parent stacking context.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

---

Put differently

> Every stacking context has a single HTML element as its root element. When a new stacking context is formed on an element, that stacking context confines all of its child elements to a particular place in the stacking order. **That means that if an element is contained in a stacking context at the bottom of the stacking order, there is no way to get it to appear in front of another element in a different stacking context that is higher in the stacking order,** even with a z-index of a billion!

...

> [...] In addition to opacity, **several newer CSS properties also create stacking contexts. These include: transforms, filters, css-regions, paged media, and possibly others**. As a general rule, it seems that if a CSS property requires rendering in an offscreen context, it must create a new stacking context.

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/